# What do you call an area where people can pick up flyers/pamphlets?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, nouns

What do you call an area/corner where people can pick up free flyers/pamphlets/brochures?
Sometimes they're on catalog stands and sometimes they're just in stacks on a table.
My non-native speaking colleagues want to call it a "take free corner" but that seems unnatural to me...
Please help me think of a better suggestion!

Comment: "Information point", perhaps? I don't think that there is a special term.

Comment: "Literature rack", "literature table", or "literature booth", depending the arrangement.

Comment: or "literature desk" or "information desk"

Comment: The strip in Las Vegas. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a *kiosk*, or more specifically an *information kiosk.*

Of the three [definitions at Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kiosk), the second applies well, and the third comes close, except for the "computer screen" part:

> 1:  an open summerhouse or pavilion
>
> 2:  a small structure with one or more open sides that is used to vend merchandise (as newspapers) or services (as film developing)
>
> 3:  a small stand-alone device providing information and services on a computer screen